# No sound after upgrading Ubuntu to 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04

I've upgraded a ThinkPad T480 to Ubuntu 22.04 from the previous LTS.  There is no longer any sound.  it either shows "Dummy Output" or incorrectly claims the speakers are disabled because the headphones are plugged in.

Sometimes rebooting or even suspend/revive fixes this. But I can't reboot my laptop several times in the hopes of fixing it.

I have checked several forums for various solutions. Nothing works.